# Failed while installing Oracle fusion Middleware 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.7)

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I am trying to install oracle fusion Middleware 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.7) on Windows 2012 R2 64-bit with Java 7 update 79. But I am receiving below error while running installation wizard:

```
Checking operating system certification
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
```

[image]

As per Oracle documentation ([Oracle Fusion Middleware Supported System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html)). The said OS should support 11g Middleware Release 1

**Note:** I can ignore the error and continue with the installation wizard. But will that lead to unexpected behavior later ? What it is the cause of this error and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Any comment why the question has been down voted ?

Answer (score 1):

FMW 11.1.0.7 is not certified with Windows 2012 R2. Refer to "certifications" tab on support.oracle.com if you have access to it.

You should consider using later release of FWM (12c) or downgrade your OS.

Comment: Can your provide the exact link for that please

Comment: Not sure if this link will work. Try it: [link](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/CertifyResults?_adf.ctrl-state=ayjwio6in_9&searchCtx=st%255EANY%257Cpa%255Epi%255E911_Oracle%2BApplication%2BDevelopment%2BFramework%257Evi%255E84336%257Epln%255EAny%257E%257C&_afrLoop=273434085927412)

Answer (score 0):

Click Start. Type %temp% in the search box, C:\users\pratapkamble\AppData\Local\Temp,
Add the following lines in your refhost.xml file located at 
C:\Users\pratapkamble\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2015-09-26_12-37-56PM\prereq\win64

Comment: Additional info on why this s a solution would help